# How can I change what python interprets as a integer?

Tags: python, integer

How can I change what python interprets as a integer? For example: 94*n would be a valid integer.

Comment: So if it interprets it as an integer, then what? You'd probably have to change the python source for that. And even so, it would pass it to C and what's C supposed to do with that?

Comment: Rewrite the grammer, then rewrite the parser. Simple ... no.

Comment: What are you aiming to achieve by doing this?

Comment: By the way, you must be at least age 12 before you can touch the python source code ;)

Comment: are you trying to make a computer algebra system or such? as like `2*n * 3*j` would be `6*n*j` if that makes any sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything is possible when you smell like Old Spice and use Python's [language services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html) to generate a AST.

Comment: How so? Can you write a custom grammar that gets converted to python by using it?

Comment: @Camilo: Exactly that. See Ren'Py for an example.

Comment: @jmeyer10: Can't, unless you explain how exactly something like `94*n` is supposed to be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

On the off chance that you're not trying to modify Python's grammar, you could use [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> n = 1.2
>>> x = 94*n
>>> type(x)
<type 'float'>
>>> y = int(94*n) # use int()
>>> type(y)
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int()` and `float()` to convert numeric types. If you want a computer algebra system in Python, then you may be interested in taking a look at [sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) which lets you do something like:

```
from sympy import *

n = Symbol('n')
x = 94*n
print x
print x.subs(n, 5)
```

If you are trying to write a computer algebra system, I would recommend using Sympy if it meets your needs or contributing to Sympy to enhance it rather than creating a whole new system from scratch.